# JQuery - How to find the id or the row that triggered the action click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML table and certain rows belong to a class and each of those rows have an id. I have attached an onclick handler to the class using jquery. When the any of the rows in that class is clicked, the click event is triggered. But the source of the event propagates to  the  element in the clicked row. How to get the id of the row that contains the td(event source) ?

HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr class="onegroup" id="parent_1">
        <td> Item 1 </td>
        <td> Item 2 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
        $(".onegroup").click(function (event) {
          alert(event.target.id); // currently displays undefined as neither of the <td> have an id.
          //Want to display the id of the row ('parent_1')
         });
```

Comment: I think you would benefit the most from reading the [**jQuery tutorial about event handling**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery you will not need to go and get for the event.target, since the context (**this**) is set to the element that is clicked and that matches the selector.
**To be clearer:**
The context will be set to the first element that accurs in event-bubbling that fits to the specified selector. 
Because of this  `$(this).is('.onegroup')` will return true always inside your handler-function, as its the selector you bound the click to.

```
  $(".onegroup").click(function () {
              alert($(this).attr("id"));
   });
```

Comment: That's not completely right. `this` will be the element that the handler is bound to, not necessarily the one that triggered the event. Nonetheless, that's exactly what the OP wants.